# Array of objects turns into Array of strings after an AXIOS call to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I'm using Axios to send a POST data to PHP.
Within the call, I'm also sending a param which is a `string` that is converted into an array of objects using `JOSN.parse()`:

```
params: {        
    'myParam': JSON.parse(string)
}
```

Everything works fine at this point. The string is properly converted into an array of objects.

When the param is being sent though, on the PHP side the array is still an array, but the objects have become strings.

Does someone have any clue about why?

Comment: Are you asking why you are not able to pass javascript objects/classes through a POST request?

Comment: I want the array of objects to not turn into array of string on the PHP side

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input and output along what you expect and what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

I figured that the right approach is the following:

Before the AXIOS call, apply `JSON.stringify()` to the array of objects.

```
'myParam': JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects) // this will be the param sent from Axios
```

Then on the PHP side, when you intercept the POST, use `json_decode()` to turn the string into the original array of object.

```
json_decode($request->all()['myParam']
```

Clean and effective.